# Max of two sub additive functions

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ be two sub additive functions.

Let $h(x,y) = \max(f(x),g(y))$.

Is $h$ a sub additive function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and trivially so. Just use the fact that $\max \{(a+b),(c+d)\} \leq \max \{a,c\}+\max \{b,d\}$

Comment: Dear Sir Thank you for your fast answer. Can you please elaborate how subadditivity is defined for bivariate functions. Is there a textbook I could refer to in this matter?

Comment: $h(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2) \leq h(x_1,y_1) +h(x_2,y_2) $. Note that $(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=(x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)$.